# Proof with Binomial identity

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

From this definition:

$\binom {x}{p} = \frac{(x)_{n}}{p!} \ \ \ \ \  p >0$

$\binom {x}{p} = 0 \ \ \ \ \ p <0$

I need to probe the following:

$\binom {r}{x}\binom {x}{p}=\binom {r}{p}\binom {r-p}{x-p} , r \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x,p \in \mathbb{N}$

I tried several ways, but cant figure out how to do it.

Comment: So, we need $$\binom {x}{p}=\binom {r-p}{x-p}$$ which requires $x=r-p$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Ok, i know we need that. But from there, can you explain a little bit your suggestion?

Comment: not sure about your query?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Sorry, i dont understand.

Comment: I believe the correct identity is $\binom{r}{x}\binom{x}{p}=\binom{r}{p}\binom{r-p}{x-p}$

Comment: @user84413 Yes, sorry for my mistake. Its fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $\binom{r}{x}\binom{x}{p}=\frac{r(r-1)(r-2)\cdots(r-x+1)}{x!}\cdot\frac{x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-p+1)}{p!}=\frac{r(r-1)(r-2)\cdots(r-x+1)}{x!}\cdot\frac{x!}{p!(x-p)!}=\frac{r(r-1)(r-2)\cdots(r-x+1)}{p!(x-p)!}=\frac{r(r-1)(r-2)\cdots(r-p+1)}{p!}\cdot\frac{(r-p)(r-p-1)\cdots(r-x+1)}{(x-p)!}=\binom{r}{p}\binom{r-p}{x-p}$.

(Here I'm writing out the falling factorials, and using the fact that $x\in\mathbb{N}$.)

Comment: Can you show me why $\frac{x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-p+1)}{p!}=\frac{x!}{p!(x-p)!}$ ?. I think im not using the fact that $x \in N$, or i dont know how to use it.

Comment: You can write $\frac{x!}{(x-p)!}=\frac{x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-p+1)(x-p)(x-p-1)(x-p-2)\cdots1}{(x-p)(x-p-1)(x-p-2)\cdots1}$, and then cancel the bottom into the top.

Answer (score 1):

You want
$\binom {r}{x}\binom {x}{p}=\binom {r}{p}\binom {r-p}{x-p}
$.

Replacing by factorials,
this is
$\dfrac{r!}{x!(r-x)!}\dfrac{x!}{p!(x-p)!}
=\dfrac{r!}{p!(r-p)!}\dfrac{(r-p)!}{(x-p)!(r-x)!}
$
or
$\dfrac{r!}{(r-x)!}\dfrac{1}{p!(x-p)!}
=\dfrac{r!}{p!}\dfrac{1}{(x-p)!(r-x)!}
$
or
$\dfrac{1}{p!(x-p)!}
=\dfrac{1}{p!}\dfrac{1}{(x-p)!}
$.

This looks correct to me.

Comment: Looks easy in this way. But i need to do it using the definition i posted with falling factorials.

Comment: I added another proof using the falling factorials.

Answer (score 1):

An answer using falling factorials
(as asked for by the OP).

You want to prove
$\binom{r}{x}\binom{x}{p}=\binom{r}{p}\binom{r-p}{x-p}
$.

Note added after OP's comment below:

You define
(with an $n$ where there should be a $p$)
$\binom{x}{p}
=\frac{(x)_p}{p!}
$
where
$(x)_p
=\prod_{j=1}^p (x-j+1)
$.

Note that,
when $x$ is an integer,
$(x)_n = \frac{x!}{(x-n)!}
$.
Use of this is indicated by
"*" below.

Also note that
$(a)_b (a-b)_c
=(a)_{b+c}
$.
Use of this
is indicated by
"**" below.

Then
(this is a sequence of equivalences)

$\begin{align}
\binom{r}{x}\binom{x}{p}
&=\binom{r}{p}\binom{r-p}{x-p}\\
\frac{(r)_x}{x!}\frac{(x)_p}{p!}
&=\frac{(r)_p}{p!}\frac{(r-p)_{x-p}}{(x-p)!}\\
\frac{(r)_x (x)_p}{x!}
&=\frac{(r)_p (r-p)_{x-p}}{(x-p)!}\\
\frac{(r)_x (x)_p}{x!}
&=\frac{(r)_x}{(x-p)!} \quad \text{**}\\
\frac{ (x)_p}{x!}
&=\frac{1}{(x-p)!} \\
 (x)_p
&=\frac{x!}{(x-p)!}\\
 (x)_p
&=(x)_p \quad \text{*}\\
\end{align}
$

Just turn this around to get the proof.